# Phonegap and UI5 orientation change

Tags: cordova, sapui5

I'm developing an application for mobile devices using SAP UI5 and Phonegap. This application is always displayed in vertical orientation and does not care on orientation change. 
I added:

```
window.addEventListener(
     "orientationchange",
     function() {
         // Announce the new orientation number
         location.reload();
     }, false);
```

But still no reaction on orientation change.

In the config.xml orintation is set to:
`<preference name="orientation" value="default" />`
in the config.xml

Answer (score 0):

From UI5 documentation:

**Orientation and Change of Orientation**

The sap.ui.Device.orientation object holds orientation information:

- landscape: Flag indicating whether the current orientation is landscape
- portrait: Flag indicating whether the current orientation is portrait

When the orientation is changed because the user rotates the device, the orientationchange event is fired by the browser, so you can handle this case as well. This event seems to be delayed in some cases, so the Device API also fires its own orientationChange event based on the browser's window resize event (which on mobile devices happens when the orientation is changed):

```
sap.ui.Device.orientation.attachHandler(function(evt) {
   if (evt.getParameters().landscape) {
      // do something...
   }
});
```

Comment: But how do I force to rerender the screen and show it in the proper orientation?